# How to calculate a time period in years and months

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to get the time a customer has been registered for, so far I've only got the months but I want to get the years and the months. There's probably a function I'm not using that works out years and months rather than just months.
Thanks

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'), (TO_DATE(REGISTER_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'))) AS 
"Registered for"
FROM A3_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 'C99166'
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `register_date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use months_between as follows:

```
Trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, REGISTER_DATE)/ 12) as year,
Trunc(Mod(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, REGISTER_DATE), 12))  as month
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 12.  But there is no need to convert `sysdate` to a date:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) / 12 AS "Registered for"
FROM A3_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 'C99166';
```

This returns decimal years.  To convert to years and months:

```
SELECT (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) / 12) || ' Years and ' ||
        MOD(FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), 12) || ' Months'
       ) AS "Registered for"
FROM A3_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 'C99166';
```

If `register_date` is stored as a date (which is should be), then don't convert that either:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, REGISTER_DATE) / 12 AS "Registered for"
FROM A3_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 'C99166';
```